# Custom pagination bullets for Swiper.js/react

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swiper.js

Been trying to add custom paginations, because I want my bullets outside of the container, but the bullets are not being rendered in the DOM.

Here is the component:

```
export function CommentSlider({ comments }: CommentSliderProps): ReactElement {
  return (
    <div className="px-4 relative">
      <Swiper
        modules={[Pagination]}
        pagination={{
          clickable: true,
          el: '.swiper-custom-pagination',
        }}
        slidesPerView={1}
        className="mt-4 h-auto !mx-0"
      >
        {comments.map(
          (comment) =>
            comment !== "empty" && (
              <SwiperSlide key={uuid()} className="!px-2">
                <div className="h-full w-0.5 bg-dark-gray absolute top-0 left-0" />
                <Comment comment={comment} />
              </SwiperSlide>
            ),
        )}
      </Swiper>
      <div className="swiper-custom-pagination" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

and the example of browser:

[enter image descriptidason here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLtCh.png)

Also tried to add this options but the resul is the same

```
      <Swiper
        modules={[Pagination]}
        pagination={{
          clickable: true,
           type: "bullets",
           el: ".comment-pagination",
           bulletClass: ".comment-pagination__item",
           renderBullet: (index, className) => {
             return `<span class="${className}" />`;
           },
          el: '.swiper-custom-pagination',
        }}
        slidesPerView={1}
        className="mt-4 h-auto !mx-0"
      >
```

Answer (score 0):

Make you have imported the `Pagination` JavaScript module and the CSS that's needed at the top, and your code should work.

```
import "swiper/css/pagination";
import { Pagination } from "swiper/modules";
```